# Ошибка: "unexpected character after line continuation chracter" в IDLE

Tags: python, syntax

Я хочу разработать echo-бота в Telegram-е, для этого нужно импортировать файл config в файл bot, обычный import config не срабатывает. Пытаюсь запустить import \Users\student\Desktop\telegrambot\config, возникает ошибка "unexpected character after line continuation chracter". В папке telegrambot помимо config расположен основной файл bot, в котором и пишу код. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Вот полный код:

```
import \Users\student\Desktop\telegrambot\config

import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

В уроке написано, что должен быть import config. И у меня есть файл с таким именем, то есть в этом плане всё должно работать, но постоянно, когда я пишу import config, выскакивает ошибка
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\student\Desktop\telegrambot\bot.py", line 1, in 
import config

Поэтому я пытаюсь импортировать этот файл  не просто через название config, а через путь к этому файлу. Я прибегаю к такому решению, потому что не понимаю, что в итоге нужно сделать, чтобы эта строка кода заработала.

Comment: Приведите ваш код, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться тем, кто захочет помочь :)

Comment: А где у вас `config` относительно основного файла лежит? И что говорит в случае ` import config`?

Comment: Импорт через указание пути к файлу нельзя сделать, только по имени модуля или через точку если он внутри какого-то пакета.

Comment: `но постоянно, когда я пишу import config, выскакивает ошибка` - какая именно ошибка?

Comment: По-моему, в php импорт такого вида :)